# Java is 2+ times faster than C (as a subset of C++)

Tags: java, c++, c, performance, optimization

The code below is a very inefficient algorithm to do multiplication. It was written as test purpose. I believe I have written the same code but in different languages.

Right below is the result of running the code.

```
OS: Windows 7
language: C (as a subset of C++)

compiler: Visual C++
optimization option: /Ox /Oi /Ot /Oy /GL
running time (seconds): 40 +/- 1

compiler: MinGW/gcc
optimization option: -O3 march=native
running time (seconds): 81 +/- 1

compiler: MinGW/g++
optimization option: -O3 march=native
running time (seconds): 82 +/- 1

language: Java

compiler: Oracle JDK
VM: Oracle JVM
running time (seconds): 18 +/- 1
```

I believe I have done something awful in my C code that the compiler with full optimization cannot in whatever way optimize out. If there are any big problem please let me know. I am planning a project that has a part dealing with large amount of computation. I decided to write this core computation part in C, but with this kind of result I may rather write everything in Java; it is lot more easier and even faster? I still believe in C, so if there are any problem in my code please let me know. What I expected was that the Java version should be 1.5 times or more slower, but it somehow outperforms C.

**Test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef signed char byte;

typedef struct _Array
{
    byte *data;
    int len;
}
Array;

void new_Array(Array *a, int len)
{
    a->data = (byte *)malloc(len * sizeof(byte));
    a->len = len;
}

void del_Array(Array *a)
{
    free(a->data);
}

typedef struct _BUI
{
    Array num;
    int len;
}
BUI[1];

void new_BUI(BUI b, const char *s)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    b->len = len;
    new_Array(&b->num, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        b->num.data[i] = s[len - i - 1] - '0';
    }
}

void del_BUI(BUI b)
{
    del_Array(&b->num);
}

int BUI_cmp(const BUI a, const BUI b)
{
    if (a->len > b->len)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a->len < b->len)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    for (int i = a->len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (a->num.data[i] > b->num.data[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a->num.data[i] < b->num.data[i])
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

#define MAX(A, B) (A > B ? A : B)

void BUI_add(BUI r, const BUI a, const BUI b)
{
    Array c;
    new_Array(&c, MAX(a->len, b->len) + 1);
    memset(c.data, 0, c.len);
    memcpy(c.data, a->num.data, a->len);
    for (int i = 0; i < b->len; ++i)
    {
        c.data[i] += b->num.data[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < c.len - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (c.data[i] >= 10)
        {
            c.data[i + 1] += c.data[i] / 10;
            c.data[i] %= 10;
        }
    }
    del_Array(&r->num);
    r->num = c;
    r->len = c.len;
    for (int i = r->num.len - 1; r->num.data[i--] == 0; --r->len);
}

void BUI_mul(BUI r, const BUI a, const BUI b)
{
    BUI c;
    new_BUI(c, "0");
    {
        BUI one;
        new_BUI(one, "1");
        BUI i;
        new_BUI(i, "0");
        for (; BUI_cmp(i, a) < 0; BUI_add(i, i, one))
        {
            BUI_add(c, c, b);
        }
        del_BUI(one);
        del_BUI(i);
    }
    del_Array(&r->num);
    r->num = c->num;
    r->len = c->len;
}

void BUI_print(BUI b)
{
    for (int i = b->len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        putchar(b->num.data[i] + '0');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    BUI a;
    new_BUI(a, "123456789");
    BUI b;
    new_BUI(b, "987654321");
    BUI_print(a);
    fputs(" x ", stdout);
    BUI_print(b);
    fputs(" = ", stdout);
    time_t start_time = clock();
    BUI_mul(a, a, b);
    time_t end_time = clock();
    BUI_print(a);
    del_BUI(a);
    del_BUI(b);
    printf("\nelapsed time: %.3f\n", (double)(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("%d %d\n", a->num.len, a->len);
    return 0;
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.util.*;

class BUI
{
    byte[] num;
    int len;

    BUI(String s)
    {
        len = s.length();
        num = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            num[i] = (byte)Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(len - i - 1));
        }
    }

    int cmp(BUI b)
    {
        if (len > b.len)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (len < b.len)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (num[i] > b.num[i])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (num[i] < b.num[i])
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void add(BUI a, BUI b)
    {
        byte[] c = new byte[Math.max(a.len, b.len) + 1];
        Arrays.fill(c, (byte)0);
        System.arraycopy(a.num, 0, c, 0, a.num.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.len; ++i)
        {
            c[i] += b.num[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < c.length - 1; ++i)
        {
            if (c[i] >= 10)
            {
                c[i + 1] += c[i] / 10;
                c[i] %= 10;
            }
        }
        num = c;
        len = c.length;
        for (int i = num.length - 1; num[i--] == 0; --len);
    }

    void mul(BUI a, BUI b)
    {
        BUI c = new BUI("0");
        {
            BUI one = new BUI("1");
            BUI i = new BUI("0");
            for (; i.cmp(a) < 0; i.add(i, one))
            {
                c.add(c, b);
            }
        }
        num = c.num;
        len = c.len;
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            System.out.print(num[i]);
        }
    }
}


public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BUI a = new BUI("123456789");
        BUI b = new BUI("987654321");
        a.print();
        System.out.print(" x ");
        b.print();
        System.out.print(" = ");
        long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        a.mul(a, b);
        long end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        a.print();
        System.out.printf("\nelapsed time: %.3f\n", (end_time - start_time) / 1000.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65295/discussion-on-question-by-xiver77-java-is-2-times-faster-than-c-as-a-subset-of).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "language: C (as a subset of C++)".

Just *No*.

C is not a subset of C++. They have common syntax (most of C) but most runtime checks are different (depends on compiler), the way the code is interpreted is different (in a few cases) and most code written for C makes for really poor C++.

C++ has quite a few facilities that would speed your algorithm implementation (not sure by how much, but if you measure correctly, you will definitely see the changes).

For a simple example, use std::string for character arrays.

> I am planning a project that has a part dealing with large amount of computation. I decided to write this core computation part in C, but with this kind of result I may rather write everything in Java;

Go for it (that is, write it in Java if it is simpler to you). You could get better performance in C, just like you could get better performance in Java. It is up to you to decide how much time and effort you put into optimizing your algorithms and code.

Computation speed will not come from running the compiler with optimization options - well, it does actually, but that's relatively small compared to speed coming from algorithmic optimizations. You could get more speed though by optimizing in a development tool chain you are familiar with, then stumbling through a language you are not familiar with.

> it is lot more easier and even faster? I still believe in C, so if there are any problem in my code please let me know. What I expected was that the Java version should be 1.5 times or more slower, but it somehow outperforms C.

Your logic is flawed.

The comparison you wrote is not representative for speed differences between C and Java (and even less between C++ and Java) in any way. It is representative for comparing these two implementations, compiled in different languages, not the languages themselves.

In other words, comparing two applications like this, even when they seem equivalent, doesn't compare the languages (or compilers) for speed. It simply compares two different programs, running very different versions of the same algorithm. It is a particular case.

Your C code is compiled. It will have different performance characteristics on different hardware (for example two processors versus four processors).

Your java code is byte-compiled. It will be optimized before running by most Java VMs, to best match the platform your code will run on.

In the end, you could probably optimize more aggressively in C or C++ than in Java, and if you need to write truly performance-critical code, than you can possibly obtain C or C++ code that cannot be matched by Java, because it would be faster than the speed threshold required to run the Java VM itself.

Such optimization though would take lots of time and effort in profiling and optimizing in particular cases, and most application domains do not need it. If you do not know if you need that level of performance, you probably don't.

Answer (score 3):

Your C version has a lot of unnecessary memory allocation which is relatively expensive. If you use an in-place addition and increment functions (see below) you can drastically increase your performance:

- Original C Code = **200 sec**
- Using In-Place Addition = **7.6 sec**
- Using In-Place Addition and Increment = **6.5 sec**

The difference in speed comes entirely from reducing the number of allocations, from 250 million (!) in the original code to 30 in the modified code. As such, your original code is really just measuring the efficiency of the memory manager in each language and not so much the actual bignum multiplication algorithm.

You can use this same optimization in the Java code to probably get similar speed improvements. Beware of playing the benchmark/optimization game too much though. With enough work on a particular version you can probably get it faster than the other one. You generally shouldn't base your language decision solely on *"X is 1% faster"*.

To use the new in-place functions simply change your multiplication loop to:

```
    for (; BUI_cmp(i, a) < 0; BUI_inc(i))
    {
        BUI_addinplace(c, b);
    }
```

The in-place addition/increment functions used are below:

```
void BUI_addinplace(BUI a, const BUI b) //a += b
{
    int maxSize = MAX(a->len, b->len) + 1;

    if (a->num.len < maxSize)
    {
        Array tmp;
        new_Array(&tmp, maxSize);

        memset(tmp.data, 0, tmp.len);
        memcpy(tmp.data, a->num.data, a->len);

        del_Array(&a->num);
        a->num = tmp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b->len; ++i)
    {
        a->num.data[i] += b->num.data[i];
    }

    int maxLen = a->len;

    for (int i = 0; i < a->len; ++i)
    {
        if (a->num.data[i] >= 10)
        {
            a->num.data[i + 1] += a->num.data[i] / 10;
            a->num.data[i] %= 10;
            maxLen = i + 2;
        }
    }

    if (maxLen > a->len) a->len = maxLen;
}


void BUI_inc(BUI a) //a += 1
{
    int maxSize = a->len + 1;

    if (a->num.len < maxSize)
    {
        ++numAllocations;
        Array tmp;
        new_Array(&tmp, maxSize);

        memset(tmp.data, 0, tmp.len);
        memcpy(tmp.data, a->num.data, a->len);

        del_Array(&a->num);
        a->num = tmp;
    }

    ++a->num.data[0];
    if (a->num.data[0] < 10) return;

    int maxLen = a->len;

    for (int i = 0; i < a->len; ++i)
    {
        if (a->num.data[i] >= 10)
        {
            a->num.data[i + 1] += a->num.data[i] / 10;
            a->num.data[i] %= 10;
            maxLen = i + 2;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (maxLen > a->len) a->len = maxLen;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your modification. And yes exactly, I was testing the memory allocators of each language. I am planning to write a program that generates huge trees consuming Gigabytes of memory, so it was on purpose to write the test code to do unnecessarily large amount of memory allocation. It was my fault to believe too much on the `malloc()` function. I will test again by making a memory pool with custom allocators for the C version and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, `malloc()` is relatively dumb and doesn't really work well with "a lot" of small allocations/deallocations. You can usually get a large performance increase by creating your own memory allocators specifically tuned to your application.

Answer (score 2):

As readily mentioned in the comments and in other answers, the bottleneck is the almost 250 million calls to malloc.

I'm usually don't write C, so excuse my non-idiomatic code, but here's a very primitive allocator (that has many limitations, may still have bugs and easy opportunities for optimization and could use a few asserts) which outperforms malloc by a lot in this case.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1048576 //reserve 1MB, although we only use 417bytes

typedef struct mem_block_hdr
{
    unsigned short size; //size of the memory block, excluding header
    char free;           //is this block free
    char cont;           //not used
}mem_block_hdr_t;

struct _myallocdata
{
    char mem[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned int highest_header_pos;
} my_alloc_data;

void init_block_hdr(void *mem)
{
    mem_block_hdr_t *head = (mem_block_hdr_t*) mem;
    head->size = USHRT_MAX;
    head->free = 1;
    head->cont = 0;
}
void init_my_alloc()
{
    init_block_hdr(my_alloc_data.mem);
    my_alloc_data.highest_header_pos = 0;
}

mem_block_hdr_t *next_header(mem_block_hdr_t *curr)
{
    return (mem_block_hdr_t*) ((char*) curr + sizeof(mem_block_hdr_t) + curr->size);
}

mem_block_hdr_t *find_next_free(unsigned int size)
{
    void * ret;
    char end_reached = 0;
    mem_block_hdr_t *head = (mem_block_hdr_t*) my_alloc_data.mem;

    while(
        (!head->free || head->size < size) &&
        ((char*) head - my_alloc_data.mem ) < my_alloc_data.highest_header_pos
        )
    {
        head = next_header(head);
    }
    return head;
}

void *my_alloc(unsigned int size)
{
    mem_block_hdr_t *header = find_next_free(size);
    unsigned int diff = (char*) header - my_alloc_data.mem ;

    if (header->size == USHRT_MAX)
    {
        header->size = size;
    }
    header->free = 0;

    if (diff >= my_alloc_data.highest_header_pos)
    {
        mem_block_hdr_t *new_high = next_header(header);
        init_block_hdr(new_high);
        my_alloc_data.highest_header_pos = ((char*) new_high) - my_alloc_data.mem;
    }
    return (void *)++header;
}

void my_free(void *mem)
{
    mem_block_hdr_t *hdr =(mem_block_hdr_t *) ((char *)mem - sizeof(mem_block_hdr_t));
    hdr->free = 1;
}

void new_Array(Array *a, int len)
{
    //a->data = (byte *) malloc(len * sizeof(byte));
    a->data = (byte *) my_alloc(len * sizeof(byte));
    a->len = len;
}

void del_Array(Array *a)
{
    //free(a->data);
    my_free(a->data);
}

//calling init_my_alloc() in main before using it
```

the numbers that I get with this are:

```
123456789 x 987654321 = 121932631112635269
elapsed time (custom alloc): 25.546
19 18
123456789 x 987654321 = 121932631112635269
elapsed time (malloc): 290.118
19 18
```

**edit:** It seems like I picked MSVC flags that are not very friendly to malloc calls, using gcc I get this:

```
123456789 x 987654321 = 121932631112635269
elapsed time (custom alloc): 30.703
19 18
123456789 x 987654321 = 121932631112635269
elapsed time (malloc): 46.406
19 18
```

I'm willing to bet there's plenty of allocator implementations out there (since it sometimes seems like every bigger C project has its own few).

Anyway, if you feel more comfortable writing Java and you think that it is sufficient for your purposes, then there's no reason why you shouldn't use it. Programming languages are just tools after all.