# Performance of Java combined with Scala project

Tags: java, performance, scala, maven-3

I'm building Rest webservice and I would like to have the best performance. I was thinking about using Scala. I read in some sources that it's faster than java. Is there any way to achieve better performance mixing java & Scala, when my project use maven? I found maven-scala-plugin but still don't know what is an influence on performance.

Comment: This is a tough question to answer without knowing specifics. What sort of performance do you need? Does it need to scale to a large number of requests, or do the requests need to return very quickly? Why do you need the best performance - Is it something required for the use case, or just a nice to have? Scala and Java both compile to bytecode that is executed on the JVM, so theoretically they would have the same performance. I would first look into developing a good maintainable solution, figuring out whether its performant enough, then optimizing the sections you need to.

Comment: Maven doesn't affect performance.

Comment: Webservice will have lots of requests per seconds and will generate reports, so it's important for me to use the best sollution (with the best performance). Yes i read that theoritically Scala and Java should work with almost the same performance, but I also read that some libraries has better libraries, for instance for quick sorting.

Comment: Neither java or scala are the best choices if you want best performance. You want a language that compiles directly to machine code.

Comment: basically, your requirement is what everybody wants. If performance is the most important factor, you need to be considering scalability. It comes down to design and methodology rather than language. If your solution is scalable, and doesn't perform well enough, you can give it more resources.

Comment: @CharlieS you can get better performance out of lower level languages, but you can also mess up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038803/java-is-2-times-faster-than-c-as-a-subset-of-c

Comment: that link shows appalling code, it's not an example of anything useful.. of course you can make faster languages run slower, which is why we use standardised benchmarks, not poorly written snippets. you need to design the code using the best constructs for the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *define* performance. A good way to define is to by using specific scenarios. 
For example -

- 99% of my REST request to complete within 1 seconds
- the REST service should provide results for 1000 concurrent clients within 2 seconds on a WAN network

Once you have an idea of this you need to design/architect your system. Performance depends on a lot of factors

- overall structure of your system
- data structures and algorithms used
- latency and bandwidth of your network
- available resources (memory, CPU and storage type)
- frameworks and libraries used
- databases
- other qualities in your system (for example, security will degrade performance)
  ...
  ...

HTH

Answer (score 5):

Java and Scala both compile to the same bytecode; more-or-less anything you can do in one you can do in the other. What is true is that sometimes Scala makes it more practical to do the things that performance requires, e.g. async I/O is much easier to work with in Scala, and `@specialized` can autogenerate implementations of generic code for primitive types, which would have to be done manually in Java. IIRC scala libraries spray and unfiltered placed highly in the techempower benchmarks before they were removed.

But those benchmarks are about theoretical performance limits you are unlikely to ever reach. In practice it's highly unlikely that you can afford the optimization effort it would take to achieve those levels of performance. "I want the best performance" is unlikely to be your real requirement. Would you spend 10x as long developing in order to have 1% better performance? If you really do need that kind of absurd level of performance, you should be able to run your own benchmarks on the scale of the techempower ones; it's a lot of work, but it's peanuts compared to the amount of work you need for "best performance" in a real program.

In more realistic scenarios, any language implementation that supports asynchronous i/o (assuming a typical REST workload here) and doesn't actively slow everything down by being full of hashtable lookups (i.e. python or ruby) is likely to be more than fast enough. *Maybe* you need parallelism (though I doubt it), but fortunately the JVM has that. You are extraordinarily unlikely to be working at the level where the difference between Scala and Java makes a difference, as long as you use a sensible framework (i.e. an async one) in either language.

And as always, the key to performance, far more than technology choices, is to measure and experiment. Profile, automatedly; look for bottlenecks, address them and measure whether your solutions worked. In any realistic codebase a few minutes profiling will produce a much greater speedup than any possible difference between Java and Scala.

Comment: far prefer this explanation to the accepted answer..